# Get the CommandButton Number from which the Click-Method was called

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a bunch of Commandbuttons with my class clsComamndButtons in a Userform. Everything works so far. All these Buttons should do the same, but i don't know how can i get the Name of the Button from which i called the cmdCommandButton_Click Method. I want to write the Path of the choosen folder in different cells, depending on the Button which was clicked.

This is my class clsCommandButtons:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cmdCommandButton As MSForms.CommandButton
Private msOnAction As String
Private mobjParent As Object

Public Property Get Object() As MSForms.CommandButton
    Set Object = cmdCommandButton
End Property

Public Function Load(ByVal parentFormName As Object, ByVal btn As MSForms.CommandButton, ByVal procedure As String) As clsCommandButtons
    Set mobjParent = parentFormName
    Set cmdCommandButton = btn
    msOnAction = procedure
    Set Load = Me
End Function

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mobjParent = Nothing
    Set cmdCommandButton = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub cmdCommandButton_Click()
    Dim sFilepath       As String                       'Pfad der gewählten .txt-Filterdatei

    'Datei öffnen - Dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Filters.Add "TextFiles", "*.txt", 1
        .FilterIndex = 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sFilepath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    Cells(Row+???Depening on the Button which was clicked), constClmn) = sFilepath
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `.name` property `cmdCommandButton.name`

Answer (score 0):

In general, to get the row of the button, usae the `BottomRightCell` property or `TopLeftCell` depending on what you what you need.

If you are using ActiveX buttons (generally advised) then something like this should be ok:

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print CommandButton1.BottomRightCell.Row
End Sub
```

---

If you are using Form elements, then assign the button-event to this and see:

```
Public Sub GetTheButtonName()
    Debug.Print "My name is ... "
    Debug.Print Buttons(Application.Caller).Name
    Debug.Print Buttons(Application.Caller).BottomRightCell.Row
End Sub
```